# Meta tags appear correct but Facebook sharing is empty (no title, description, or image)

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This problem exists for all pages on this site. The meta tags appear correct but whether you use the share link on the site, or try to share direct on FB, the image, title and description are not used.

There must be a legitimate issue as the Sharing Debugger also shows an empty/plain sharing dialog. But the Facebook share debugger isn’t given me any helpful info. It sometimes shows a 302, which I don’t understand as there is no redirect on the site. Refreshing the scrape sometimes shows an error Unknown Image Error, which also doesn’t seem to be a legitimate issue.

Almost always the Facebook share debugger shows a 302 the first time and then follows with other unhelpful errors.

Maybe a DNS issue, weird that it would be site wide.

Example Links:

```
[http://pikespeakharleyownersgroup.com/group-riding-pphog-405/][1]
[http://pikespeakharleyownersgroup.com/tell-tires-toast/][2]
[http://pikespeakharleyownersgroup.com/30th-annual-high-country-toy-run/][1]
```

Any and all help is very appreciated.

Comment: Seems like the URL is doing a 302 redirect to the same URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging your page URL on below link:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Once you scan your URL, on the link I provided, you will see "Warnings That Should Be Fixed" section. Try resolving warnings mentioned in that section.

Hope this will help you!